# Counter not working properly

Tags: c#, counter

I have some code that looks like this:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (var line in theCP4UnknownList.Distinct())
{
    var splitUnknowns = line.Split(' ');

    i++;
    unknownCP4Counter = unknownCP4Counter - i;

    KTS_Save saveForm = new KTS_Save (splitUnknowns[0], splitUnknowns[1], splitUnknowns[3], splitUnknowns[4], openDataBase2File.FileName, unknownCP4Counter);

    saveForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is display how many unknown parts there are and decrease the counter on each form.

So if there were 10 parts, the first form to pop up for the user would have a "10" in the upper right corner. After the user exits out of the current form, a new form will pop up and have "9" in the upper right corner.... This would continue to happen until it reached 0. Which is also when the forms would stop coming since the `unknownCP4Counter` is set to how many items are in `theCP4UnknownList`.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? It seems to be outputting a "0" on every form.

### EDIT:

```
    private string _Name;
    private string _PtpName;
    private string _TapeWidth;
    private string _FeederPitch;
    private string _DataBaseFileName;
    private int _Counter;

    public KTS_Save()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public KTS_Save(string Name, string PtpName, string TapeWidth, string FeederPitch, string DBFileName, int Counter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _Name = Name;
        _PtpName = PtpName;
        _TapeWidth = TapeWidth;
        _FeederPitch = FeederPitch;
        _DataBaseFileName = DBFileName;

        nameTextBox.Text = _Name;
        ptpNameTextBox.Text = _PtpName;
        tapeWidthTextBox.Text = _TapeWidth;
        feederPitchTextBox.Text = _FeederPitch;
        counterLabel.Text = _Counter.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: We would need to see the code of the `KTS_Save` form.

Comment: @Otiel: Ouch. I was setting the _Counter equal to nothing.. and I was not setting the counterLabel to the actual Counter... Thank you for making me check my code again. If you post an answer I will surely accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found it by yourself. We learn from our mistakes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
int i = 0;
int unknownCP4Counter = theCP4UnknownList.Distinct().Count; // 10
foreach (var line in theCP4UnknownList.Distinct())
{
    i++;
    unknownCP4Counter = unknownCP4Counter - i;
}
```

you are doing:

```
unknownCP4Counter = 10;
// foreach starts
unknownCP4Counter = 9;
unknownCP4Counter = 7;
unknownCP4Counter = 4;
unknownCP4Counter = 0;
unknownCP4Counter = -5;   
unknownCP4Counter = -11;
unknownCP4Counter = -18;
unknownCP4Counter = -26;
unknownCP4Counter = -35;
unknownCP4Counter = -45;
// foreach stops
```

If you want to create a decreasing counter, I suggest you to do instead:

```
int unknownCP4Counter = theCP4UnknownList.Distinct().Count; // 10
foreach (var line in theCP4UnknownList.Distinct())
{
    unknownCP4Counter--;
}
```

---

**EDIT** based on OP's edit:

You forgot to initialize the `_Counter` field in your constructor `KTS_Save` with the `Counter` parameter. As *int* is not a nullable type, its default value will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

What is unknownCP4Counter initialized as?  It is being detracted by i each time and if it is initialized to the total count then i will be always be total - total which is 0.  Perhaps you meant to write:

```
unknownCP4Counter = i;
```

?

Comment: OP said : *unknownCP4Counter is set to how many items are in theCP4UnknownList*

Comment: Thanks Otiel, but items was still a little vague to me hence the question of initialization.  I do like your point of i "exploding" and therefore the counter ending up being vastly negative, I had missed that part.  However, this seems to be a job for the debugger, and inspecting exactly what the data is when it reaches this code segment.